# Add a <location /> element to applicationHost.config through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis

Does anyone know of a way to add a new root level `<location />` element to the *applicationHost.config* file via the `WebAdministration` cmdlets?  There is `Get-WebConfigurationLocation` (and "Remove" and "Rename" versions of the cmdlet), but not an "Add."  I've tried many different ways to do this using `Add-WebConfiguration` but I have not had any success.

Some of the things I've tried:

```
  Add-WebConfiguration -Filter '/' -AtIndex 0 -Value @{ location = @{ site='bobDev' } }
  Add-WebConfiguration -Filter '/' -AtIndex 0 -Value '<location site="bobDev" />'
  Add-WebConfiguration -Filter '/' -AtIndex 0 -Value @{value="bobDev.html" }
```

I know that the `Value`s I'm trying aren't probably correct, but I'd at least like to see *something* get added into my *applicationHost.config*.

Comment: What *exactly* have you tried? What *exactly* were the results? How were the actual results different from the expected result? Did you get errors? What did they say?

Comment: The results were always the same.  Nothing changed in the applicationHost.config file.
I appreciate your help, but I honestly believe it just does not work. The reason being is that <location /> elements are children of the <configuration /> element, but the Add-WebConfiguration cmdlet does not have a way to address that very specific case.  Everything else that is done with Add-WebConfiguration collections addresses a collection property, but there isn't a "location collection" property that can be accessed.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you solved your problem. It has been years. I came across your post. I just wanted to share how I solved my problem so that others can use it as needed.

This link helped a lot: [Generate Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/using-configuration-editor-generate-scripts)

The following lines will add a new location and also add parameters to your location.

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'mysite/devtest' -filter "system.webServer/security/ipSecurity" -name "." -value @{ipAddress='10.200.0.0';subnetMask='255.255.0.0';allowed='True'}

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'mysite/devtest' -filter "system.webServer/security/ipsecurity" -Name "."  -value @{allowUnlisted="false";enableProxyMode="true";denyAction="NotFound"}
```

Output:

```
  <location path="mysite/devtest">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" enableProxyMode="true" denyAction="NotFound">
          <add ipAddress="10.200.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" allowed="true" />
        </ipSecurity>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```